# Parameters of a function used by the contained anonymous inner class are modified by "final". But why?

Tags: java, anonymous-class

```
public Destination destination(final String dest, final float price) {
    return new Destination() {
        private int cost;
        {
            cost = Math.round(price);
            if (cost > 100)
                System.out.prinltn("Over budget!");
        }
        private String label = dest;
        public String readLabel() { return label; }
    };
}
```

Parameters used by the contained anonymous inner class are modified by "final". But why?

Answer (score 1):

Regarding to the rule applies to *inner classes* [(JLS 8.1.3)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.1.3):

> Any local variable, formal method parameter or exception handler parameter used but not declared in an inner class **must be declared final**. 
>   Any local variable, used but not declared in an inner class **must be definitely assigned before the body of the inner class**.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732544/why-are-only-final-variables-accessible-in-anonymous-class)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But i want to kwon why there is such a rule. Hope someone give a deeper answer.

Comment: Please refer to the link, it describe this issue in details.